# print value into sed -n

Tags: sed, grep

I use sed to get the content of file from a desire point but I have a problem.

I can not print `$variable` value into this sed command

```
count=$(sed -n '/$variable/,$p' file.log | grep '"KO"' -c)
```

I try with double quotes and close the single but not working

`count=$(sed -n "/$variable/,$p" file.log | grep '"KO"' -c)` ERROR unexpected `,'
`count=$(sed -n '/'$variable'/,$p' file.log | grep '"KO"' -c)` ERROR unterminated address regex

I know that the sed reseach is letteral "$variable" but I can not pass the value...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Contain a dynamic string ex: [17-09-12 00:01:03]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a question of getting the quoting right.

Your first example:

```
count=$(sed -n '/$variable/,$p' file.log | grep '"KO"' -c)
```

doesn't expand `$variable` because it's in single quotes, the second:

```
count=$(sed -n "/$variable/,$p" file.log | grep '"KO"' -c)
```

expands `$variable` but has issues with its contents, as mentioned by *choroba*. It also has issue with the `$p` which will be interpreted as a shell variable. Your third example:

```
count=$(sed -n '/'$variable'/,$p' file.log | grep '"KO"' -c)
```

comes pretty close to what you need, but still suffers if `$variable` contains characters that sed treats specially, so these need to be escaped, e.g. the following works:

```
variable="\[17-09-12 00:01:03\]"
count=$(sed -n '/'$variable'/,$p' file.log
```

And as brackets are also special to the shell you can escape them automatically with the `printf` `%q` directive:

```
variable="[17-09-12 00:01:03]"
variable=$(printf "%q" "$variable")
count=$(sed -n '/'$variable'/,$p' file.log
```

Answer (score 1):

`[` has a special meaning in `sed`. I would use something more powerful than `sed`, i.e. Perl. It can escape the variable for you:

```
perl -ne '/\Q'"$variable"'\E/ and print'
```

Comment: ... thanks again but i can't use perl :(
however, I just do it with remove [] (isn't important for result) and replace the "white space" with \s 

ex: 17-09-12\s00:01:03

now, sed work ok, maybe ^_^